# Assembly x86 append numbers to a variable

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I'm reading an input numeric string, iterate it character by character to convert each digit in decimal.

Now at every iteration in one of my register, example `AL`, i have the single digit, let's say

```
Input: 12345678
Iteration_1 : 1
Iteration_2 : 2
...
Iteration_8 : 8
```

I would like to add these integers to a `DD` variable, so that at the end of the iteration i would have a `DD` variable containing the whole number that i could use for operation.

Has this sense? How could i append at each iteration the current number to the DD variable?

Answer (score 0):

Zero out a register to use as a "result so far".

top:

Get a character.

Make sure you really have a valid decimal digit.

Subtract '0' to convert a character to a number.

Multiply "result so far" by ten.

Add in the new number.

Go to top.

This is what I use...

```
;--------------------
atoi:
; expects: address of string on stack
; returns: number in eax
; "trashes" ecx and edx
; actually, edx is "next character"
; and ecx (cl) is the "invalid" character
; think of "192.168.0.1"...
; caller cleans up stack
push ebx

mov edx, [esp + 8]  ; pointer to string
xor ebx, ebx ; assume not negative

cmp byte [edx], '-'
jnz .notneg
inc ebx ; indicate negative
inc edx ; move past the '-'
.notneg:

xor eax, eax        ; clear "result"
.top:
movzx ecx, byte [edx]
inc edx
cmp ecx, byte '0'
jb .done
cmp ecx, byte '9'
ja .done

; we have a valid character - multiply
; result-so-far by 10, subtract '0'
; from the character to convert it to
; a number, and add it to result.

lea eax, [eax + eax * 4]
lea eax, [eax * 2 + ecx - '0']

jmp short .top
.done:
test ebx, ebx
jz .notminus
neg eax
.notminus:
pop ebx
ret
;------------------------
```

Now just `mov [myvar], eax`. This has some disadvantages! I just quit on any invalid character. This catches a zero-terminated string, or a linefeed-terminated string (as I get from Linux), or whatever. Fine, but I don't get to yell at the user if they screw up. Also I can't check for overflow. If you need that, ditch the "cute trick" and go with `imul eax, 10`... If you don't need to deal with negative numbers, it can be simplified a bit.

Comment: i can't use 32-bit registers in my emulator (dos-box), would it work the same with 16-bit AX BX CX DX ?

Comment: Ahh, no. 16-bit addressing modes are limited. The same general algorithm should work, but you'll need to use different registers. DosBox won't let you use 32-bit registers? What a bummer! (I'm embarrassed to admit I've never succeeded installing it) Getting a 32-bit result in `dx:ax` is possible, but a PITA. Give it a shot (maybe try 16-bit result first) and holler if you need more help.

Comment: Come up with an error `invalid effective address` at lines `lea eax, [eax + eax * 4]` and `lea eax, [eax * 2 + ecx - '0'`, guess cannot use operands in `LEA` parameters :(

Comment: DOSBOX do not prevent us for using 32 Bit-Register.

Comment: Maybe an assembler directive is missing for to use 32 bit instructions. For MASM add ".386" at the top in your source.

Answer (score -2):

```
MOV CX, #8
loop:
MOV DX, #1
ADDS AX, DX
ADDS DX, #1
SUBS CX, CX, #1         
BNE loop  
DD dw 0  
MOV DD, AX
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful here. Also, code formatting.

Comment: `DD` won't work as a label name in most assemblers; it's the 32-bit version of a `dw` directive / pseudo-instruction.  Also, NASM doesn't use `#` on immediates the way ARM does.  And `subs reg, reg, #1` is also an attempt to use an ARM instruction and syntax with x86 register names.  x86 doesn't have `adds`, x86 `add` *always* sets FLAGS, and you can't stop it.